# Question marks inserted in mysql database

Tags: php

When i'm trying to insert Arabic characters in MySQL, It inserts question marks although it was working well locally

Also I added the set Character set code for db connection as follows :

```
mysqli_query($dbcon,"SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
mysqli_query($dbcon,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

All my php files is UTF8 character set also database files is utf8_general

Comment: First try adding `mysqli_set_charset($db,"utf8");` after you connect

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: I already added the following line: 
mysqli_query($dbcon,'SET CHARACTER SET utf8');